# Python condensing tuple's to first value

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of tuples that output

```
[('city 1', '#' ), ('city 1', '#' ), ('city 2', '#' ), ('city 2', '#'), etc...]
```

What I need to do is to add up all of each city's # value and output a list such that:

```
[('city 1', 'sumof#' ), ('city 2', 'sumof#' ), ('city 3', 'sumof#' ), ('city 4', 'sumof#'), etc...]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you want. May be this?:

```
>>> d = [('city 1', 2 ), ('city 1', 1 ), ('city 2', 2 ), ('city 2', 4)]
# Have an empty dictionary to calculate and store result
>>> r = {}
# Iterate through the list
# As the list contains tuples with 2 elements, we can just 
# make use of unpacking
>>> for city,count in d:
        # dict.setdefault will try to get the city count, but
        # if not exists (first time) it will return the provided
        # default value; 0 here. Just add up.
        r[city] = r.setdefault(city,0) + count

# items() contains the key-value pair. May be this is the result?       
>>> r.items()
[('city 2', 6), ('city 1', 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do without importing any external module, just create some logic here :

```
data=[('city 1', 1), ('city 1', 3), ('city 2', 5 ), ('city 2', 9)]

def sum_tuples(data):
    track={}
    for i in data:
        if i[0] not in track:
            track[i[0]]=i[1]
        else:
            track[i[0]]+=i[1]

    return [(key,value) for key,value in track.items()]
print(sum_tuples(data))
```

output:

```
[('city 1', 4), ('city 2', 14)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = [('city 1', 2 ), ('city 1', 1 ), ('city 2', 2 ), ('city 2', 4)]

sum_values = defaultdict(list)

for city, value in d:
    sum_values[city].append(value)

>>> print([(city, sum(values)) for city, values in sorted(sum_values.items())])
[('city 1', 3), ('city 2', 6)]
```